# How to add customUI onload automatically inside PowerPoint "RibbonX" using VBA code?

Tags: vba, office365, powerpoint, ms-office, ribbonx

I'm trying to add customUI onload automatically inside PowerPoint "RibbonX", but I can't find any way to use VBA code for that!
Can anyone please help me with that?

Comment: You might try the [`PresentationOpen` event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/powerpoint.application.presentationopen)

Comment: @PeterT, firstly thank you, I swear i tried it several times, but my problem was for PowerPoint to start running VBA code with start, so I used customUI to help me, but they requested this process to run automatically using another VBA code to import customUI parts from the existed file, and I still can't find any way for that.

Answer (score 0):

The `onLoad` callback is called only when it is declared in the Ribbon XML markup. The [customUI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/aa338199(v=office.12)?redirectedfrom=MSDN#customui) element contains the corresponding attribute for that.

```
<customUI … OnLoad="MyAddinInitialize" …>
```

Read more about the Fluent UI (aka Ribbon UI) in the following series of articles:

- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 1 of 3)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/aa338202(v=office.12)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)
- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 2 of 3)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/aa338199(v=office.12)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)
- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 3 of 3)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/aa722523(v=office.12)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)